# Rouche's theorem for different disks of different sizes

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kz^k$ be an entire function which is not a polynomial.
For each $N>1$, set $s_N(z)= \sum_{k=0}^N a_kz^k$, for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Prove that for each $R>0$, there exists an integer $M_0>1$ such that for all $N \geq M_0$, the function $s_N(z)$ has at least one root outside of the disk $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|\leq R\}$

Since we are dealing with number of roots, I think we will need Rouche's theorem.

Let $R>0$.

Choose $M_0$ so that $|\sum_{k=0}^{M_0-1}a_kR^k| < |\sum_{k=M_0}^{N}a_kR^k|$.

Then by Rouche's theorem, $S_N$ and $\sum_{k=M_0}^{N}a_kR^k$ have the same number of roots in side $D$. So $s_N$ has $N-M_0$ number of roots inside $D$.

Could someone please let me know if my proof is correct? If not, how would I approach this problem. I feel like my $M_0$ is too vague.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $M_0$ does not exist whenever $a_k$ tends to $0$ 'rapidly'.

Answer (score 1):

If, $p_n(z)\to f(z)$, $\deg(p_n)=n$, $f$ is entire, and all zeros of all $p_n(z)$ are located in some compact set, then $f(z)$ is the zero function.

This follows immediately from the fact that $f(z)$ will have an infinite number of zeros (counting multiplicity) bounded in the compact set. That is, $f(z)$ will have an accumulation point of zeros that are bounded. This is referred to as the uniqueness theorem.